# Strange processes in task manager (Network Restricted, No Impersonation, No Network)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, task-manager

I have strange entries in task manager.

What can this mean?

[image]

**UPDATE**

For example, I have the following in regedit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Svchost`

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: there is nothing strange

Comment: ok, then the question is what do these remarks mean?

Comment: this is defined here and controls the permissions of the services: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Svchost**